# How to increase the space of /dev/mapper/vg_var-lv_var

Tags: partitioning, mount

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf831.png)

How to increase the disk space of /dev/mapper/vg_var-lv_var

I have tried with resize command but it gave this message3 "The filesystem is already 2595840 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!"

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize LV first and then the filesystem.

Use `sudo vgs` to check how much space is left in your`vg_var` volume group. Then resize your LV with `lvresize -L +1G lv_var` to add 1 GB (if available).

Only after that run the filesystem resize command as you tried before.